# How to craft a type matching "a list with a single element of type Int"?

Tags: haskell

I am currently writing my very first program in Haskell.

In the specification I am working with, `[0] 5` is used to define a MAC key that could be written `"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"::ByteString`.

I somewhat fancy the idea of reusing that notation (even though it makes very little sense from a programming perspective). Eventually writing `mackey` so that `mackey [0] 5` does the right thing was simple enough.

The only question that remains is how to *define my input type* so that it *enforces* the use of a list with a **single** *integer element*. Is that even possible?

---

NB: normally, I wouldn't bother too much about that. I shouldn't even use a list in such case: a simple `Int` would be enough and "enforce" everything I need; so I know that the correct way is to use a simple integer. But this is a very good way to explore what can be done (or not) with Haskell type system. :)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which, AFAIK, isn't part of 'standard' Haskell.

Comment: Take a look here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-list-0.1.6/docs/Data-FixedList.html

Comment: Amazing! Such flexibility. That gives me ideas! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've observed yourself, *a single `Int`* does exactly what's needed and is probably the way to go. Don't use a list if you don't *want* a list!

That said, using a plain `Int` may not be the best thing either. Perhaps you want to be clear what's the meaning of each argument. You might for that purpose make an alias for `Int` and call it accordingly:

```
newtype KeyWord = KeyWord Int

macKey :: KeyWord -> Int -> MAC
```

In this case the syntax at the call site would then be `macKey (KeyWord 0) 5`.

It would be possible to shorten that a bit more, but it's probably not worth it. In fact, even the `newtype` is probably overkill – the main benefit is that the type signature becomes more explicit, but for calling the function this is mostly boilerplate. A simple type-alias is probably enough:

```
type KeyWord = Int
```

and then you can again write `macKey 0 5` while retaining the clear signature.

If you need to write out lots of those keys in a concise manner, you might consider making `macKey` and infix operator:

```
infix 7 #*
(#*) :: KeyWord -> Int -> MAC
```

and then write `0#*5`.

Comment: Could you also cite @Eugene_Sh. comment for fixed-length lists? Then I'll accept your answer. :)

Comment: Such fixed-length lists gain you absolutely nothing useful for your application. After all, your question is not really about single-element-constricted lists but about _syntax with square brackets_.

Comment: Hum, yes and no... It has more to do with the type system, really. I just came up with that (real) example thinking "oh, that notation is neat, would it be possible to (ab)use Haskell type system in such a way?". So, while I understand that it makes no sense from a programming perspective, It is much much much easier to reason about such a simple case rather than real life, complex, cases where using fixed-length lists would actually make sense. That being said, what you wrote obviously makes sense.

Comment: Well, Haskell's syntax is flexible, but certain things are hardbaked, including that `[]` is for lists (or, with the [`OverloadedLists` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=overloadedlists#ghc-flag--XOverloadedLists), list-like types such as arrays). If you want to use square-bracket syntax for something entirely different, you'll need a different syntactic environment. You can write a parser for that with e.g. [megaparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec), and embed it in your Haskell file with a QuasiQuote.

Comment: Incidentally, you _could_ abuse `OverloadedLists` to write `[0] :: KeyWord`, but this would lead to runtime errors when somebody writes `macKey [] 2` or `macKey [32,542] 3`.